# Flag a node but create a view of the nodes that reference it

Tags: views, entities, flags

We want our logged in users to be able to Flag/Follow our "Fisheries" content type nodes. Users can then create a "Catch" node in the Catches content type and use an entity reference field (Fisheries) to tag the Fishery in which it was caught.

I therefore want to be able to produce a view which shows what's being caught in the Fisheries that the user follows. If they follow 10 Fisheries the View would contain the latest catches from those 10 lakes in date order.

I can see what Fisheries the user is following with this View:

[image: See what nodes a user is following]

but I want to see what other content type nodes are referencing this node instead. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Entity View Attachement](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/eva-7.x-1.2.tar.gz) module. This module attaches a view to an object. this object may be a node, user , ...  . Select the appropriate bundle and it works well